# pip fails to download requirements for jupyter

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I'm on a linux machine and want to download a python package (jupyter) and all of it's requirements for another python version and platform (windows 64 platform). So I enter:

`pip download --python-version='36' --implementation='cp' --platform='win_amd64' --only-binary=:all: jupyter`

But then the following error occurs:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter
```

That's because PyPI only has the source version of `pandocfilters` package. You can check it here > 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandocfilters/1.4.2

I can only see three solutions:

1. Use another method (other than pip) to download all jupyter requirements;
2. Use a flag to tell pip to go ahead if an error occurs (an error like the one above). Have searched extensively and haven't found;
3. Write my own code that will read all requirements of jupyter (and the requirements of the requirements and so on) and will download them individualy.

Having already google arround for the first two solutions and haven't found anything, I go for the third solution. But I just can't dismiss the feeling that I'm reinventig the wheel!

Is there a more straightforward way to accomplish my goal (download all package requirements including pandocfilters for jupyter)?

Comment: what python version u have selected "36" is it valid??

Answer (score 1):

You want to use version `3.6`, not `36`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately your solution does not work.Have you tried yourself? It fails for `tornado`. It seems it does not download the packages by the same order when you change `--python-version='36'` to `--python-version='3.6'`. But you can see `tornado` is like `pandocfilters`, both only have source versions on PyPI.